# How to get children in circular map

Tags: javascript, tree

Maybe I'm just stupid but I cannot get this to work right now.
I try to get all the children of a property inside an object, following an array of child props. It should include all the nodes the way down in the structure.

Basically the arrays as values, contain more props that are also present in the map. It is kind of fake tree structure.

This is the input:

```
const input = {
  a: ["b", "c"],
  b: ["d", "e"],
  c: ["f", "g"]
}
```

As the output I expect the result of a function call like `getChildrenOfProp(input, "a")` to result in this:

```
getChildrenOfProp(input, "a");
// results in ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
// because "b" & "c" are present in map and have more children ..

getChildrenOfProp(input, "b");
// results in ["d", "e"]
// no more children because "d" & "e" are not present in the map ..
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the second argument?

Comment: The property to get all the children for. @Nikhil Aggarwal

Comment: Can you explain it little further ? I don't think I quite get it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are dealing with anything that even vaguely resembles a tree, you're likely going to want recursion.

Something like this would work:

```js
function getChildrenOf(input, target) {
  let result = [target];
    
  // recurse through children
  if (input[target]) {
    input[target].forEach(child => result = result.concat(getChildrenOf(input, child)));
  }
 
  return result;
}

const input = {
  a: ['b', 'c'],
  b: ['d', 'e'],
  c: ['f', 'g'],
  h: ['i', 'l'] // not gotten with a
}

console.log(getChildrenOf(input, 'a'))
```

Basically, go through once and add the target itself and then loop through its children and add them all together.

If you don't want it to contain `a` itself, then you can use this slightly tweaked version instead:

```js
function getChildrenOf(input, target, result) {
  result = result || [];
    
  // recurse through children
  if (input[target]) {
    input[target].forEach(child => { 
      result.push(child);
      getChildrenOf(input, child, result)
    });
  }
 
  return result;
}

const input = {
  a: ['b', 'c'],
  b: ['d', 'e'],
  c: ['f', 'g'],
  h: ['i', 'l'] // not gotten with a
}

console.log(getChildrenOf(input, 'a'))
console.log(getChildrenOf(input, 'b'))
```

Comment: The tweaked one did it! Thanks!